# Failing assign permissions to user SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Very odd problem occurs when I try to assign permissions to a single user by using the name picker. I have two users that has similar names: Jason Hillmer and Jason Hill.
When permission is assigned to Jason Hillmer everything is working as expected, but when trying to assign any permission to Jason Hill it fails saying: **"The user does not exist or is not unique."**. I've checked into the database from which SharePoint 2010 sources the users and they are totally different, with different emails, last names, usernames and so on.

Actually I don't have any way to grant access to Jason Hill into SharePoint website.

Does anybody know how to solve this problem? Is there a way to trick the system? And I would like to know WHY this problem occurs when we have two totally different users, even if they have similar names...

Regards, 
Martin

Answer (score 0):

Generally when you receive the "does not exist or is not unique" message, you can click the underlined name to see available options and choose the correct user.

Another way to accomplish the same would be to type in the user's email address or login instead of their "friendly" display name, since those unique values should resolve to the correct account immediately.